# cAdvisor prometheus integration returns container_cpu_load_average_10s as 0

Tags: docker, monitoring, prometheus, cadvisor

I have configured Prometheus to scrape metrics from cAdvisor. However, the metric "container_cpu_load_average_10s" only returns 0. I am able to see the CPU metrics under the cAdvisor web UI correctly but Prometheus receives only 0. It is working fine for other metrics like "container_cpu_system_seconds_total". Could someone point if I am missing something here?

Prometheus version: 2.1.0

Prometheus config:

`scrape_configs:
- job_name: cadvisor
  scrape_interval: 5s
  metrics_path: /metrics
  scheme: http
  static_configs:
  - targets:
    - 172.17.0.2:8080`

cAdvisor version: 0.29.0

Comment: What does the metric look like on the /metrics endpoint directly?

Comment: It looks like this
"container_cpu_system_seconds_total{some list of parameters/labels} 0"

Comment: if the metric prometheus can read is always zero then the issue is with whatever is calculating that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to get the metric `container_cpu_load_average_10s`, the cAdvisor must run with the option

```
--enable_load_reader=true
```

which is set fo false by default. This is described [here](https://github.com/google/cadvisor/blob/master/docs/runtime_options.md).

Comment: it still doesn't work for me(
entrypoint: /usr/bin/cadvisor -logtostderr -enable_load_reader=true

Comment: Same, I'm getting errors like this: `W1128 07:45:13.721484       1 container.go:380] Could not initialize cpu load reader for "/docker": failed to create a netlink based cpuload reader: failed to get netlink family id for task stats: netlink request failed with error errno 0`

Comment: have the same issue, found this:
> the Task Stats netlink family (which cAdvisor uses to collect load stats) doesn't work within a network namespace. You'll need to either run your cAdvisor container in the host network (--net=host), or run outside of a container entirely.

https://github.com/google/cadvisor/issues/1287

Answer (score 0):

If the value is zero, it means the container is idle.
You don't need 'enable_load_reader'. I don't enable it as it may make cAdvisor unstable.
Some useful links:

[Linux Load Averages: Solving the Mystery](https://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2017-08-08/linux-load-averages.html)

[High CPU utilization but low load average question](https://serverfault.com/questions/667078/high-cpu-utilization-but-low-load-average)

[cAdvisor enable_load_reader](https://github.com/google/cadvisor/blob/master/docs/runtime_options.md#cpu)