# Pass flag to cAdvisor with docker

Tags: docker, cadvisor

I am running cAdvisor using the following code as instructed [here](https://github.com/google/cadvisor):

```
sudo docker run \
  --volume=/:/rootfs:ro \
  --volume=/var/run:/var/run:ro \
  --volume=/sys:/sys:ro \
  --volume=/var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:ro \
  --volume=/dev/disk/:/dev/disk:ro \
  --publish=8080:8080 \
  --detach=true \
  --name=cadvisor \
  google/cadvisor:latest
```

I need to pass the following flag to cAdvisor as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49126197):

> --enable_load_reader=true

How do I pass that flag to cAdvisor?

Answer (score 1):

The `google/cadvisor` container behaves like the binary itself, therefore you can just append the option to the end of the `docker run ...` command.
You would also like to add the `--net host` option to your `docker run` command as noted [here](https://github.com/google/cadvisor/issues/1287#issuecomment-219521836):

```
sudo docker run \
  --volume=/:/rootfs:ro \
  --volume=/var/run:/var/run:ro \
  --volume=/sys:/sys:ro \
  --volume=/var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:ro \
  --volume=/dev/disk/:/dev/disk:ro \
  --publish=8080:8080 \
  --detach=true \
  --net host \
  --name=cadvisor \
  google/cadvisor:latest \
    --enable_load_reader=true
```